# gitでマージする際に差分があるのにAlready up to dateと表示されてしまう

Tags: git, github

リモートブランチにdevelopブランチとAブランチがあり、Aブランチのデータをマージしたいと思っています。
developブランチにて、
`git merge A`
としてコマンドを打ったのですが、Already up to dateとなって反映できない状況です。
developブランチとAブランチの差分を見てみたらあるようなのですがこの場合何を確認すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: ブランチ間の違いはどのように確認しましたか？git diffコマンドを利用した? ソースを目検？

Comment: diffツール使って、ソースを確認しました。

Comment: リモートリポジトリとローカルリポジトリの同期は取れていますか？

Comment: @cubick♦ 両方ともできています。

Comment: 同期については意味を調べて理解しました。

Comment: `git branch -a -v` の実行結果を質問中に貼り付けてみてください。

Comment: @cubick そのコマンドを実行したら、ミスが発覚しました。一文字似た名前で過去ブランチがあり、マージしたいブランチ名とは違い、コマンド打っていました。